# map list object into select box in jsp page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl, el

In Spring Java Application i have Bean class in this one property have list of other bean object

```
private List<Course> courseName = new ArrayList<Course>();
-------//Setter and getter
------
```

And Course bean have property `id`,`name`

in my controller class.. i'm adding `List<Course>` using `setCourseName(-)`

now i'm display the this course bean `name` list in the jsp page using spring form tags ..

```
  <form:form action="form1" modelAttribute="COURSE">
        <c:set var="modalAttributeName" value="COURSE" />
        <c:set var="modalAttribute" value="${requestScope[modalAttributeName]}" />
             <form:select path="courseName" class="month_select"                                    items="${modalAttribute.courseName.name}">
    </form:select>
 </form:form>
```

But this is not working ... give me any suggestion

`

```
Exception: `
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
`
```

But if we write only courseName empty select box display

```
<form:select path="courseName" class="month_select" items="${modalAttribute.courseName}">

    </form:select>
```

Comment: "Is not working". What do you mean? Do you get an error? Is the bean not displayed? Posting the error would help a lot.

Comment: Seems that you haven't accessing to `${courseName}` or whatever its name as request attribute is...

Comment: From your edit: make sure your `${modalAttribute.courseName}` variable is not empty. Try the naive `<c:out value="${modalAttribute.courseName}" />` and then printing all its contents using `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: Display forEach tag simple but i want select box is it Possiable in forEach tag?

Comment: You can do a select using a for each and outputing each form:option manually, or using the form:options JSTL.  This blog has an example of how to use both:  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Comment: Any luck finding the answer?